# Repeat task each time different number of minutes

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, repeat

I need my app to execute a method each x minutes. But x can be different each time: It can change between 15 and 60 depending on other factors.

The method has to be executed even if the user has closed the app or even if the user has restarted the phone.

I am trying with the AlarmManager but I don't know if is the best way for my case.
Is it? Or is AlarmManager a resource consuming way?

Comment: You need more details if you want a truly useful answer, but it does sound like `AlarmManager` would be ideal.

Comment: AlarmManager is fine, as well as a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver to reschedule the alarms when the phone was restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an IntentService and override onHandleIntent:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    updateLocationInBackground(); // or whatever task you need to do every x minutes
    scheduleNextUpdate();
}
```

The method simply does this:

```
private void scheduleNextUpdate() {
    new Scheduler().start();
}
```

Scheduler thread would look like this:

```
private class Scheduler extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(UserLocationUpdaterService.this, UserLocationUpdaterService.this.getClass());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(UserLocationUpdaterService.this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        /* Replace this part with your computation as to when the next trigger should happen. Mine is set to fire off every 5 minutes.*/
            long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTime + (5 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextUpdateTimeMillis, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

Fire off this Intent with startService() either on your main Activity, or on some BroadcastReceiver that has BOOT_COMPLETED registered, or both.

Comment: UserLocationUpdaterService is the class implementing IntentService, isn't?. I am getting the error: 'The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Scheduler' too

Comment: Scheduler class should be defined inside the IntentService as well, as an inner class. This way when it calls getSystemService it's actually calling intentService.getSystemService.

Comment: What's the explanation for create the Scheduler class instead write all code inside the run() method in the scheduleNextUpdate() method?

Comment: that's just how I did it, you don't have to follow it by the letter. my aim was to have a clean and understandable onHandleIntent.